# Importing `createjs` in React project is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, createjs

I saw several similar posts about issues I'm facing but none of them was actually helpful. That's why I post a duplicate question here.

I built a react project using `npx create-react-app [app_name]` and installed createjs using `npm install createjs` but simply importing `createjs` module is not working.

Working directory is as follow :

[image]

`createjs` is imported inside `Create.js` file and I did the followings:

1. `import createjs from "createjs";`
   `import {createjs} from "createjs";`
   `import * as createjs from "createjs";`

--> Module not found: Can't resolve 'createjs' in `[my_project_path]\src\dialog\interactive`

2. `import createjs from "../../node_modules/createjs/build/1.0.0/createjs"`

--> this actually seems to locate the module but shows another exception.
[image]

I also checked my `package.json` and `package-lock.json` file but they all contains `createjs` inside.

package-lock.json:

[image]

package.json:

[image]

How can I import createjs module properly in a react app? Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding @types for this createjs? That'll give you more insight as in what's the correct exported member from this library

Comment: @Mohit what do you mean by adding @types? in import statement?

Comment: No, I meant typings file for createjs. It should tell you exactly what kind of exported member you've to use from this lib.

Comment: I don't think the NPM module you install via `npm install createjs` is one that's designed to be imported and used in front end development. I think it's the build stuff so that you can make custom builds. I also can't find ANY examples of this NPM approach for `createjs`, which lends me to believe you'll have to do it via adding a script tag in your HTML to a CDN and then just accessing it globally